# How to convert each row of the first column as a header and second as a row?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I want a SQL query that convert each rows of the first column as a header and second columns as a row so how can we do that using SQL.. below is a example:

In my table records like

```
    FieldName   Value   link
-----------------------------
    Country     India     1
    Country     USA       2
    Country     Russia    3
    Amount      10000     1
    Amount      20000     2
    Amount      30000     3
```

Result should be :

```
Country Amount
---------------
India   10000
USA     20000
Russia  30000
```

please let me know if anyone have an idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know which Amount belongs to which Country?

Comment: @ Martin Smith  we can considered first for first ..and second for second at this moment and I am using SQL Server.

Comment: There is no "first" in a relational database. If you don't have some other column that links the rows together you are out of luck.

Comment: We can assume that first country has amount and second have second amount like that ..

Comment: We can't assume that because the rows have no guaranteed order nor is there any guarantee that they will be read in any particular order.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. By definition a table is an unordered set. The concept of order is during data retrieval. You need to have something to use as a way to order the rows.

Comment: I have updated the exists table..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ([demo](http://rextester.com/EBDMJS4952))

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'Country' THEN Value END) AS Country,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'Amount' THEN Value END) AS Amount
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY link
```

Comment: It will give only the row with have max value:                                                      
    Country Amount
    USA   3000000

Comment: @User125 - it gives your desired results. See demo link. It is expected that `(link, FieldName)` will be unique.

Comment: where is the demo link ?

Comment: The link attached to the word "demo" in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
select a.Value, b.Value
from (select Fieldname, Value, link from theTable) as a
    inner join (select Fieldname, Value, link from theTable) as b on a.link = b.link
where
    a.FieldName > b.FieldName;
```

Comment: Hi buddy its not working ..means not giving the require output..thanks